# Creating file on SDCard

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with backing up my database to SDCard.
Target SDK: 25
Phone SDK: 23

Also Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() method is not working properly for me (becouse it returns internal storage path).

I am using another method to get path to my SD Card which returns me:
/mnt/media_rw/8209-21EA

when the getExternalStorageDirectory() returns:
/storage/emulated/0

I went to /mnt/media_rw/8209-21EA through ES and this is real path for SDCard on my phone.

At least ES is using /storage/8209-21EA/ path to access my SD.

So, when I'm trying to call "file.mkdirs()" on

```
    file = new File(getRemovebleSDCardPath() + "/data/com.indi.passwords");
```

this method gives me "false" and doesn't create any folder.

I am using this code to get permissions:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            1);

                }
            }
```

and

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

in my manifest file.

Any ideas how to make that works?

Comment: may be redundant but my intuition says that you might want to add READ permission too.

Comment: It worked on SDK 22 without "read" perm, but thanks :) I will add em

Answer (score 0):

use this to get SD card path

```
Context.getExternalFilesDirs();
```

Note that it may return null if the SD card is not mounted or moved during the access. Also, you might need to add these permissions to your manifest file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() method is not working properly for me (becouse it returns internal storage path).

[External storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), and neither of those are [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

> At least ES is using /storage/8209-21EA/ path to access my SD.

Unless "ES" was pre-installed on your device, it has no more rights to work with removable storage than you do.

> So, when I'm trying to call "file.mkdirs()" on `file = new File(getRemovebleSDCardPath() + "/data/com.indi.passwords");` this method gives me "false" and doesn't create any folder.

Correct. You do not have direct filesystem access to arbitrary locations on removable storage.

> I am using this code to get permissions:

Those permissions do not relate to removable storage.

> Any ideas how to make that works?

If "that" is your existing code, that is not possible, except perhaps on rooted devices.

If "that" is write some data to removable storage, your choices are:

- Use `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, or `getExternalMediaDirs()`, all methods on `Context`. If they return 2+ items in their array return values, the second and subsequent ones are on removable storage. You can read and write those locations without any permissions.
- Or, use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to allow the user to choose where to place the data, which may or may not be removable storage. Call `openOutputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in the `Uri` you get back from your `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` request. Use that `OutputStream` to write your content.

Comment: File paths[] = new File[10];
        paths = getExternalFilesDirs(null);

Comment: File paths[] = new File[10];
        paths = getExternalFilesDirs(null);

paths[1]    worked for me, thank you very much

Comment: What if I don't want to delete my database during uninstalling app ?

Comment: @Maciek: Tell the user to eject their removable storage before uninstalling your app. You do not have direct filesystem to any location on removable storage where files will remain after your app is uninstalled. The `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` approach can allow your content to remain after your app is uninstalled, but you do not control where that content goes, and you only have stream access, not filesystem access.